# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL leaks and datawithContentsOfURL:options:error reports the URL is nil?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsdata, nsurl, core-foundation

I'm implementing a concurrent imageLoader for a table, along the lines of the Apple Dev. video on NSOpertaion.

The interesting thing (at least to me), is that inside my NSOperation's main, among other stuff, I have this line of code (where imageURL is a valid url string, stored and retained as an ivar in the NSOperation):

```
UIImage * newThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
```

The above code works, but instruments reports a CFHTTPCookieStorage leak when calling NSData dataWithContentsOfURL. So seems like a CF leak.. not much I can do about that one. Someone, though, said if they switched to dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error the leak would not occur.

So I went ahead and tried that, meaning the above line turns into:

```
UIImage * newThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] options:0 error:&error]];
```

But then I get an exception for the same URLWithString that previously worked!:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument'
```

What gives?

Comment: I was getting the same NSInvalidArgumentException saying that my NSURL object is nil because I wasn't escaping my URL strings (using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) before passing them to the NSURL constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a wrapper for Grand Central Dispatch rather than using NSOperations. You can check out one I wrote a while ago here: https://github.com/MaxKDevelopment/MKImageCenter.

Comment: I mean, thanks.. and I'll check it out. But still, I'm not doing anything weird.. Should be able to use NSOps just fine. And dataWithContentsOfURL, as far as I know is not threaded. The NSop is, but the NSData method should be running synchronously inside the child process spawn by NSOp. To me this sounds like a bug in Apple's  SDK. Though I might be wrong.